# MySQL: Return only rows in one table where ALL values in one column of another table are the same

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables joined by a foreign key:

```
main           secondary
----           --------------------        
 id             main_id(FK) | flag
----           --------------------  
  1                1          1
  2                1          1
  3                1          1
  4                2          0
                   2          1
                   3          0 
                   3          1
                   4          1 
                   4          1
```

I need to construct a query that will only return rows from 'main' if their corresponding rows in 'secondary' ALL have a flag = 1. In this example, the query should only return rows 1 and 4 from 'main'.

```
main
----
 id
----
  1
  4
```

I've played around with COUNTs and NOT EXISTs, but I'm missing something fundamental here. The basic, stripped-down query I started with is:

```
SELECT main.id from main WHERE main.id IN (SELECT secondary.main_id from secondary WHERE flag = 1);
```

What other conditions do I need to set in order to get my desired result set?

Comment: try including distinct in your inner uery

Comment: Can the flag only ever be 1 or 0 - or are any values allowed?

Comment: @P.Salmon: The flag can only ever be 1 or 0, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a not in a subselect for flag <> 1

```
SELECT main.id 
from main 
WHERE main.id NOT IN (SELECT secondary.main_id 
                             from secondary WHERE flag <> 1);
```

Comment: Good answer. You should remove `DISTINCT` from the subquery though. You should only tell the DBMS *what* to do not *how* to do it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner   correct .. thanks  .. answer  updated

Comment: Short & sweet. Seems to be working, so far. The NOT IN was what was eluding me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query

```
SELECT id 
FROM (
    SELECT id, COUNT(1) = SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) is_valid
    FROM tableName
    GROUP by id)t1
WHERE is_valid = 1;
```

Hope this would help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach which doesn't assume knowledge of the flag values (but does assume they are integers) would be to check the min and max values by main id

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select  id
    -> from main
    -> where id in
    -> (
    -> select  t.main_id from
    -> (
    -> select  s.main_id,min(s.flag) minflag, max(s.flag) maxflag
    -> from secondary s
    -> group by s.main_id
    -> ) t
    -> where t.minflag = t.maxflag
    -> ) ;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    4 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```